# WiFI Direct for cordova windows platform

Tags: c#, cordova, uwp, cordova-plugins, cordova-win10

I need to connect windows devices using wifi direct. Our application is cordova application. Below is the code for wifi direct advertising that I wrote. Complete code executing without error and `m_Publisher` status is changed after executing `start()`. But other devices still can't see the WiFi Direct device.

```
function enableStartWiFiDirect() {

    var Api_DeviceName = Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.displayName;
    m_Publisher = Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher();
    m_Listener = new Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectConnectionListener();

    m_Listener.addEventListener("onconnectionrequested", onConnectionRequested);

    m_Publisher.advertisement.IsAutonomousGroupOwnerEnabled = false;

    m_Publisher.advertisement.ListenStateDiscoverability =
        Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectAdvertisementListenStateDiscoverability.Normal;

    var IE = new Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectInformationElement();

    // IE blob
    var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();
    dataWriter.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf16LE;
    dataWriter.writeString(Api_DeviceName);
    IE.Value = dataWriter.detachBuffer();


    // OUI
    var dataWriterOUI = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();
    dataWriterOUI.writeBytes([0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC]);//(Globals.CustomOui);
    IE.Oui = dataWriterOUI.detachBuffer();

    IE.ouiType = 12;//(byte)Api_DeviceName.Length;

    m_Publisher.advertisement.informationElements.push(IE);

    m_Publisher.start();
    console.log('WiFi Direct Started');

    return "Advertisment started sucessfully";
}
```

Hope someone can help me with these problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could start WiFi Direct advertisement from below in cordova app.

```
startAdvertisment: function (successCallback, errorCallback, args) {

        if (publisher === null) {
            publisher = Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher();
        }

        if (listener===null) {
            listener = new Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectConnectionListener();

            listener.onconnectionrequested = OnConnectionRequested;
        }
        publisher.advertisement.isAutonomousGroupOwnerEnabled = false;

        publisher.advertisement.listenStateDiscoverability =
            Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectAdvertisementListenStateDiscoverability.normal;
publisher.start();

    }
```